# How can I copy a range of rows from excel to txt file

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm slowly working my way in using Power shell. I have a number of excel files (500+) having a column formula that I would like to save in a new '.txt' file. I already created a script that would lookup the files one by one on a given folder. My question now is how can I copy a range of columns from excel to a text file.

[image]

here is what I've been working on:

```
#Set the start and end range of the Formula column
$NewMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

$FormulaRange = $Sheet.range("G5:G$NewMax")
$FormulaRange.Copy() | out-null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling and testing here is the solution I landed with:

```
#Set the start and end range of the Formula column
$NewMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

$FormulaRange = $Sheet.range("AQ6:AQ$NewMax")
$FormulaRange | select text | Export-Csv "c:\\output\sample.txt" -NoTypeInformation
(Get-Content "c:\\output\sample.txt") | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | out-file -FilePath "c:\\output\sample.txt" -Force -Encoding ascii
```

First I exported the selected range into a csv file which I saved in a .txt extension. Then I removed the quotation makes on each row using the replace function.

Answer (score 0):

You could pasted the data into a new Excel file and then save it as .txt.

After you:

```
$FormulaRange.Copy()
```

Do this:

```
$wb = $app.Workbooks.Add()
$ws = $wb.Worksheets(1)
$ws.Paste()
$app.DisplayAlerts = $False
$wb.SaveAs("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Book2.txt", -4158) # xlText
$wb.Close($False)
$app.DisplayAlerts = $True
```